# Dataframe query with non-standard column names

Tags: pandas

In my Dataframe, there is a column named "Gold" and one named "Gold.1".

I can say:

```
df.query('Gold >= 1')
```

But when I say:

```
df.query('Gold.1 >= 1')
```

I get an error message:

```
Gold .1 >=1
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is probably because the column name is not a valid Python identifier. How can I run this query?

Comment: It seems now it is not [implemented](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6508)

Answer (score 1):

What about the following workaround:

```
In [50]: df
Out[50]:
       Gold    Gold.1
0  0.214436 -2.677897
1 -1.179001  0.414095
2 -0.574168 -0.594181
3  0.091198  0.526241
4 -0.035557 -2.543000
5 -1.760054  1.113350
6 -0.195420 -0.451129
7 -0.016121 -0.231368
8  0.596189  0.410589
9 -0.499686  0.320909

In [51]: qry = 'Gold.1 >= 1'

In [53]: df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('.', '__')) \               
           .query(qry.replace('.', '__')) \
           .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('__','.'))
Out[53]:
       Gold   Gold.1
5 -1.760054  1.11335
```

Explanation:

rename 'Col.Suf' to 'Col__Suf'

```
In [56]: df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('.', '__'))
Out[56]:
       Gold   Gold__1
0  0.214436 -2.677897
1 -1.179001  0.414095
2 -0.574168 -0.594181
3  0.091198  0.526241
4 -0.035557 -2.543000
5 -1.760054  1.113350
6 -0.195420 -0.451129
7 -0.016121 -0.231368
8  0.596189  0.410589
9 -0.499686  0.320909
```

make the same replacement in the query

```
In [57]: df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('.', '__')).query(qry.replace('.', '__'))
Out[57]:
       Gold  Gold__1
5 -1.760054  1.11335
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following which takes 'Gold.1' as a single valid column name:

```
df[df['Gold.1'] >= 1]
```

Example:

```
from numpy.random import randn
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame(randn(10, 2), columns=['Gold','Gold.1'])
df[df['Gold.1'] >= 1]

    |  Gold         | Gold.1
---------------------------------
2   | -1.371181     | 1.126188
3   | 0.379097      | 1.345582
5   | -2.390853     | 2.157693
7   | 1.365850      | 1.098555
```

Or more complex query:

```
df[df['Gold'] > df['Gold.1']]  

    |  Gold         | Gold.1
---------------------------------
0   | -0.146086     | -0.403966
7   | 1.365850      | 1.098555
9   | 1.154098      | 0.738376
```